# Most basic linear algebra equation in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Let's say I have the following system of equation:

```
x  + y = 3
5x - y = 3
```

Here `x=1` and `y=2`. Using scipy or some other linear algebra solver, what would be the most basic way to do this. For example, something like:

```
A = np.array([1,1],[5,-1])
A'inverse = [3,3] # how to do this?
```

Comment: The best way is to do your own basic research. You have access to some of the most powerful search tools in history. I would feel quite comfortable recommending any one of the more popular ones

Comment: See [`numpy.linalg.solve`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html).  The docstring includes an example.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for the suggestion, yes I've posted an answer to this question using something similar with `numpy.linalg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the suggestion of using `np.linalg` by aminrd:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(([1,1],[5,-1]))    # initialize 2x2 matrix
B = np.array([3,3])             # initialize the (x,y) column vector 
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)        # get A'
np.matmul(A_inv,B)              # Ax = B --> x = A'B
# array([1., 2.])
```

Here we can see the answer is `X=1, Y=2`, which is what we expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linear algebra part of Numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array(([1,1],[5,-1]))

# Calculating inverse of A 
B = np.linalg.inv(A)
# array([[ 0.16666667,  0.16666667],
#       [ 0.83333333, -0.16666667]])

# Calculating matrix multiplication of B and A: Expecting Identical Matrix
np.matmul(B,A)
# Very close to 0 and 1
# array([[ 1.00000000e+00,  2.77555756e-17],
#       [-5.55111512e-17,  1.00000000e+00]])

# Converting to integer
np.int32( np.matmul(B,A) ) 
# array([[1, 0],
#       [0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```